# Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple´2´ is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou usando asp.net mvc e no meu controller, tenho o código abaixo:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult salvaItem(items item)
    {
        items oItem = new items()
        {
            address = item.address,
            bairro = item.bairro
        };
        return ("ok", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

na linha do return, estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple´2´ is not defined or imported

e também

> Cannot implicitly convert type '(string, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior AllowGet)' to 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'  cadastro    D:\OneDrive\VisualStudio2017\siteBuscaFree\cadastro\cadastro\Controllers\HomeController.cs  25  Active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O primeiro erro, acontece para quem usa a versão inferior do .NET 4.6.2:

> Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple´2´ is not defined or imported

Você precisa instalar o pacote ou mudar a versão .NET 4.6.2 para cima:

`Install-Package "System.ValueTuple"`

O segundo erro:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '(string,
>   System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior AllowGet)' to
>   'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'

Você esqueceu especificar o tipo de retorno (`Json`) e você deve fazer algo assim:

```
return Json("ok", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```